# ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME Teléfono y whatsapp

Tags: android-studio

Buenas estuve buscando en Internet pero no logro hacer funcionar las soluciones que veo en mi código. Tengo una web dentro de una app la cual al pulsar sobre el teléfono o Whatsapp me da el típico error.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
            @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

                mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
                mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-0000000000000000000/0000000000");
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }

                });

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://dominioejemplo.es");

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView mWebView;
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale logre hacer funcionar el telefono y ciertos enlaces añadiendo las siguiente lineas que vi en otra pregunta a la cual agradezco a su usuaria por ayudar. Pero **no logro hacer funcionar para que me abra //whatsapp.....**

```
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                return false;
            }

           //Agregar validación para email y telefono. 
           if( url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") ) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
              startActivity(intent);
           }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lo solucioné de esta manera: de esta forma ya no te daria error el webview, te cargaba al inicio, con el else te carga perfecto**

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView webView, final String url) {

           

            if (url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {

                Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                startActivity(whatsappIntent);

                return true;
            }else{
               webView.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return false;
        }
```